# Adding and editing values in array

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have a problem with merging two similar arrays.

They both have a similar structure.

```
$array1 = array(
    'A' => array (
        'money_in' => 0,
        'money_out' => 0
     ),
    'B' => array (
        'money_in' => 0,
        'money_out' => 0
     ),
    'C' => array (
        'money_in' => 0,
        'money_out' => 0
     )
);
```

and the second one

```
$array2 = array(
    'A' => array (
        'money_in' => 0,
        'money_out' => 0,
        'type' => 'new'

     ),
    'C' => array (
        'money_in' => 0,
        'money_out' => 0,
        'type' => 'edit'
     )
);
```

So I want to accomplish this. If type in second array is new then i want to insert array with key A in front of A in first array and then iterate keys so that A in that array becomes B, B becomes C etc..
If type is edit then i want to override value of the same keys. So C in second array will override C in second array.

I have been having troubles with this some time so i decided to ask the stackoverflow community for help :)

Thank you!

Comment: And when inserting, `Z` will become .. ?

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo Z will become AA

Comment: and what if there are order-collisions? I.e. you have keys `A` and `B` and incoming array has `new` for `A` and `edit` for `B`. If we'll handle `A` first, then original `A` value will become `B` key, and then - what we should update? Original `B` (which will be `C` now) or new `B` (after inserting `A`)?

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo The second array has all the right keys for editing and inserting. I made sure of that. It's not influenced by first array.

Comment: Did not get that, sorry. I.e. all types in incoming array could be either **all** `new`  or **all** `edit`? By the way, if we have two keys: `A` with `new` and `B` with `new`: yet again, after inserting `A` this will be `A`(new A), `B`(old `A`), `C`(old `B`). What should we do with incoming `B`? I.e. before which element it should be inserted?

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo if B is incoming with type insert it will be inserted before B, the old B will become C etc..

Comment: I'm still seeing ambiguous conditions here. Please, clarify in question (all those cases I've asked above)

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo It's not ambiguous, the second array will never change and it doesn't depend on the changes of the first array. Only first array is changing. It really isn't to hard to understand.